# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns' -> when I didn't even change dataframe into np.ndarry

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Currently I am trying to crack the Spaceship Titanic Dataset from Kaggle and when I was in the process of doing so I got an error (below). In the code below `X` is the same dataset after removing the Transformed Feature from it.

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

class Cleaner(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        X = X.drop(["Name", "PassengerId", "FoodCourt", "ShoppingMall", "Cabin"], axis=1)
        return X

class ObjectEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        columns_to_encode = ["HomePlanet", "CryoSleep", "Destination", "VIP"]
        encoder = OneHotEncoder()
        
        # Encode each attribute and add the columns to the DataFrame
        for column in columns_to_encode:
            matrix = encoder.fit_transform(X[[column]]).toarray()
            column_names = [f"{column}_{i}" for i in range(matrix.shape[1])]
        
            for i in range(len(matrix.T)):
                X[column_names[i]] = matrix.T[i]

        # Remove Old Parameters
        X = X.drop(["HomePlanet", "CryoSleep", "Destination", "VIP"], axis=1)

        return X

class LabelYEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
        y_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)
        return y_encoded

class NullImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        features_with_missing_values = X.columns[X.isnull().any()].tolist()
        imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
        X[features_with_missing_values] = imputer.fit_transform(X[features_with_missing_values])
        return X

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("cleaner", Cleaner()),
    ("object_encoder", ObjectEncoder()),
    ("label_y_encoder", LabelYEncoder()),
    ("null_imputer", NullImputer()),
])
X = pipeline.fit_transform(strat_train_set)
```

This Code Produces an error :-

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 X = pipeline.fit_transform(strat_train_set)

File ~/Projects/Cracking-Spaceship-Titanic/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:1152, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1145     estimator._validate_params()
   1147 with config_context(
   1148     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1149         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1150     )
   1151 ):
-> 1152     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File ~/Projects/Cracking-Spaceship-Titanic/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py:479, in Pipeline.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    477 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
    478 if hasattr(last_step, "fit_transform"):
--> 479     return last_step.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    480 else:
    481     return last_step.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step).transform(Xt)

File ~/Projects/Cracking-Spaceship-Titanic/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py:157, in _wrap_method_output.<locals>.wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    155 @wraps(f)
    156 def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 157     data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    158     if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
    159         # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
    160         return_tuple = (
    161             _wrap_data_with_container(method, data_to_wrap[0], X, self),
    162             *data_to_wrap[1:],
    163         )

File ~/Projects/Cracking-Spaceship-Titanic/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:916, in TransformerMixin.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    912 # non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
    913 # method is possible for a given clustering algorithm
    914 if y is None:
    915     # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 916     return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    917 else:
    918     # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
    919     return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

File ~/Projects/Cracking-Spaceship-Titanic/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py:157, in _wrap_method_output.<locals>.wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    155 @wraps(f)
    156 def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 157     data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    158     if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
    159         # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
    160         return_tuple = (
    161             _wrap_data_with_container(method, data_to_wrap[0], X, self),
    162             *data_to_wrap[1:],
    163         )

Cell In[19], line 7, in NullImputer.transform(self, X)
      6 def transform(self, X):
----> 7     features_with_missing_values = X.columns[X.isnull().any()].tolist()
      8     imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
      9     X[features_with_missing_values] = imputer.fit_transform(X[features_with_missing_values])

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Comment: But `sklearn` coukd have.  It's scipy/numpy based, so may not know about or ue the pandas extras like row and column labels.  Select the desired columns before fitting or encoding.

Answer (score 0):

From sklearn-template [docs](https://sklearn-template.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html):

> Note that transform takes only X as input and is expected to return the transformed version of X

So now in `transform` method of your `LabelYEncoder` class the `X` dataframe is replaced with `y_encoded` which is `'numpy.ndarray'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to build some custom classes for a preprocessing pipeline. I don't know what version of `scikit-learn` you're using, but anything prior to  `1.2.X` would attempt to convert input to a `np.ndarray`. The [`set_output`](https://scikit-learn.org/1.2/whats_new/v1.2.html#id8) method changed this behavior.

## `scikit-learn` 1.3.2

If you're able to upgrade, then the error you raise will change to this:

```py
class Cleaner(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X = X.drop(["Name", "PassengerId", "FoodCourt", "ShoppingMall", "Cabin"], axis=1)
        return X

class ObjectEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        columns_to_encode = ["HomePlanet", "CryoSleep", "Destination", "VIP"]
        encoder = OneHotEncoder()
        # Encode each attribute and add the columns to the DataFrame
        for column in columns_to_encode:
            matrix = encoder.fit_transform(X[[column]]).toarray()
            column_names = [f"{column}_{i}" for i in range(matrix.shape[1])]
            for i in range(len(matrix.T)):
                X[column_names[i]] = matrix.T[i]

        # Remove old parameters
        X = X.drop(["HomePlanet", "CryoSleep", "Destination", "VIP"], axis=1)
        return X

class LabelYEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
        y_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)
        return y_encoded

class NullImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        features_with_missing_values = X.columns[X.isnull().any()].tolist()
        imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy="median")
        X[features_with_missing_values] = imputer.fit_transform(X[features_with_missing_values])
        return X

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("cleaner", Cleaner()),
        ("object_encoder", ObjectEncoder()),
        ("label_y_encoder", LabelYEncoder()),
        ("null_imputer", NullImputer()),
    ]
)

df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

# "In the code below X is the same dataset after removing the Transformed Feature from it."
# Idk what "Transformed Feature" is, but I assume you mean "Transported"
strat_train_set = df.drop(columns="Transported")

X = pipeline.fit_transform(strat_train_set)
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 61
     57 # "In the code below X is the same dataset after removing the Transformed Feature from it."
     58 # Idk what "Transformed Feature" is, but I assume you mean "Transported"
     59 strat_train_set = df.drop(columns="Transported")
---> 61 X = pipeline.fit_transform(strat_train_set)

File ~\Sandbox\PRIVATE-RAI\env\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1152, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1145     estimator._validate_params()
   1147 with config_context(
   1148     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1149         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1150     )
   1151 ):
-> 1152     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File ~\Sandbox\PRIVATE-RAI\env\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:471, in Pipeline.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    444 """Fit the model and transform with the final estimator.
    445 
    446 Fits all the transformers one after the other and transform the
   (...)
    468     Transformed samples.
    469 """
    470 fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 471 Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    473 last_step = self._final_estimator
    474 with _print_elapsed_time("Pipeline", self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

File ~\Sandbox\PRIVATE-RAI\env\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:377, in Pipeline._fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    375     cloned_transformer = clone(transformer)
    376 # Fit or load from cache the current transformer
--> 377 X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    378     cloned_transformer,
    379     X,
    380     y,
    381     None,
    382     message_clsname="Pipeline",
    383     message=self._log_message(step_idx),
    384     **fit_params_steps[name],
    385 )
    386 # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    387 # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer
    388 # from the cache.
    389 self.steps[step_idx] = (name, fitted_transformer)

File ~\Sandbox\PRIVATE-RAI\env\Lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py:353, in NotMemorizedFunc.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    352 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 353     return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\Sandbox\PRIVATE-RAI\env\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:957, in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    955 with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    956     if hasattr(transformer, "fit_transform"):
--> 957         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    958     else:
    959         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

File ~\Sandbox\PRIVATE-RAI\env\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py:157, in _wrap_method_output.<locals>.wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    155 @wraps(f)
    156 def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 157     data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    158     if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
    159         # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
    160         return_tuple = (
    161             _wrap_data_with_container(method, data_to_wrap[0], X, self),
    162             *data_to_wrap[1:],
    163         )

File ~\Sandbox\PRIVATE-RAI\env\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:916, in TransformerMixin.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    912 # non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
    913 # method is possible for a given clustering algorithm
    914 if y is None:
    915     # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 916     return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    917 else:
    918     # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
    919     return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

File ~\Sandbox\PRIVATE-RAI\env\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py:157, in _wrap_method_output.<locals>.wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    155 @wraps(f)
    156 def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 157     data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    158     if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
    159         # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
    160         return_tuple = (
    161             _wrap_data_with_container(method, data_to_wrap[0], X, self),
    162             *data_to_wrap[1:],
    163         )

Cell In[21], line 33, in LabelYEncoder.transform(self, X)
     31 def transform(self, X):
     32     label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
---> 33     y_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)
     34     return y_encoded

NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

You can fix this by editing your :method:`LabelYEncoder.transform` to accept a `y` argument. But personally, I'd modify your custom classes to be more generic and use a `ColumnTransformer` to control the inputs to each step. Something like the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder

# Separating `X` and `y`
df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
X = df.drop(columns="Transported")
y = df.Transported

cols_to_drop = ["Name", "PassengerId", "FoodCourt", "ShoppingMall", "Cabin"]
cols_to_one_hot = ["HomePlanet", "CryoSleep", "Destination", "VIP"]
# Remove the `cols_to_drop` and `cols_to_one_hot`.
# The remainder will be passed through via the identity function.
cols_to_keep = X.drop(columns=[*cols_to_drop, *cols_to_one_hot]).columns

prep_trf = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        # One hot encode the `cols_to_one_hot`
        ("one_hot", OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False), cols_to_one_hot),
        # Impute the `cols_to_keep`
        ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median"), cols_to_keep),
    ],
    # Drop the remaining columns not mentioned in 
    # `cols_to_one_hot` or `cols_to_keep`
    remainder="drop",
    verbose_feature_names_out=False,
    # Transform output to `pandas.DataFrame` (optional)
).set_output(transform="pandas")

# Apply the transformations to `X`.
X = prep_trf.fit_transform(X)
```

Calling `prep_trf.fit_transform` on `X` will handle all the preprocessing of your input features. Because `LabelEncoder` only takes `y` as an input and doesn't support the :method:`set_output`, you can't add it to the `prep_trf` object. In fact, [you technically can't add it to a pipeline without some custom code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12720). Instead you should transform the `y` variable independently, or ignore it altogether (since it's already in binary form with boolean values).

## `scikit-learn` 1.1.3 (< 1.2.X)

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder

# Separating `X` and `y`
df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
X = df.drop(columns="Transported")
y = df.Transported

cols_to_drop = ["Name", "PassengerId", "FoodCourt", "ShoppingMall", "Cabin"]
cols_to_one_hot = ["HomePlanet", "CryoSleep", "Destination", "VIP"]
# Remove the `cols_to_drop` and `cols_to_one_hot`.
# The remainder will be passed through via the identity function.
cols_to_keep = X.drop(columns=[*cols_to_drop, *cols_to_one_hot]).columns

prep_trf = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        # One hot encode the `cols_to_one_hot`
        # NOTE: had to change the `sparse_output` parameter to `sparse`.
        ("one_hot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), cols_to_one_hot),
        # Impute the `cols_to_keep`
        ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median"), cols_to_keep),
    ],
    # Drop the remaining columns not mentioned in 
    # `cols_to_one_hot` or `cols_to_keep`
    remainder="drop",
    verbose_feature_names_out=False,
    # NOTE: :method:`set_output` does not exist in scikit-learn version < 1.2.X
)

# Apply the transformations to `X`.
X_ = prep_trf.fit_transform(X)
```

Because `scikit-learn` version 1.1.3 doesn't have the :method:`set_output`, we need to recreate the `pandas.DataFrame` ourselves:

```py
X_v1_1_3 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=X_,
    # Track the index just incase it was modified earlier.
    # This can affect `joins`.
    index=X.index,
    # Use the :method:`prep_trf_get_feature_names_out` to get the 
    # correct column names.
    columns=prep_trf.get_feature_names_out(),
)
```

The output will be the same in both scenarios. Apply the `LabelEncoder` to `y` independently in both versions.

Additional resources:

- [`1.1.X` implementation of `TransformerMixin`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ffc0f66676b4835eb1bdd3f3ecab025e9c1be9fe/sklearn/base.py#L836)
- [`1.2.X` implementation of `TransformerMixin`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/364c77e047ca08a95862becf40a04fe9d4cd2c98/sklearn/base.py#L838)
- [Introducing the set_output API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_set_output.html#introducing-the-set-output-api)